# java: package com.amazonaws.regions does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ses

I am new to spring boot and aws java sdk. I am trying to use spring boot to send an email. Currently when i import any of these

```
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailService;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.Body;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.Content;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.Destination;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.Message;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.SendEmailRequest;
```

I always get `java: package com.amazonaws.regions does not exist` error. I actually get a similar error for each of my imports.

Here is a sample of my dependencies in pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.temporal</groupId>
        <artifactId>temporal-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.98</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.98</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am currently using java sdk version is 17.0.1
Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get that class name? I didn't find it anywhere on Central.

Comment: what class name are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Both of those classes are contained in the aws-lambda-java-core jar, which is distributed separately from the AWS SDK. You can download it from maven central at the link above if you're not using maven/gradle/some other build system that can natively pull from maven central.

Comment: Hey Ankit, thanks for responding to my question. I added this to my pom.xml `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>` but still got the same error